# Is it wrong practice to modify function arguments?

Tags: python, function, methods, containers

Is it a bad practice to modify function arguments?

```
_list = [1,2,3]
def modify_list(list):
    list.append(4)

print(_list)
modify_list(_list)
print(_list)
```

Comment: modifying function arguments is fine! (but better not use `list` as a variable)... be careful when you modify default arguments (unless you know what you are doing); e.g: `def f(lst=[]): ...`.

Comment: depends on what the function *should* be doing really. the 2nd example (now removed), almost always bad because of the global though. But modifying function args is okay as long as it is abundantly clear the function is supposed to do such a thing. A good rule of thumb that python also uses in many places is pairing functions that modify with a return None.

Comment: Os a convention to return none for functions that change objects in place :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first it was supposed to be a comment, but it needed more formatting and space to explain the example. ;)

If you:

- know what you're doing
- can justify the use
- don't use mutable default arguments (they are way too confusing in the way they behave, I can't imagine the reason their use would *ever* be justified)
- don't use global mutables anywhere near that thing (modifying mutable global's contents AND modifying mutable argument's contents?)
- and, most importantly, document this thing,

this thing *shouldn't* cause much harm (but still might bite you if you only *think* you know what you're doing, but in fact you don't) and can be useful!

---

Example:

I've worked with scripts (made by other programmers) that used mutable arguments. In this case: dictionaries.

The script was supposed to be run with threads but also allowed single-thread run. Using dictionaries instead of return values removed the difference of getting the result in single- and multiple-thread runs:

Normally value returned by a thread is encapsulated, but we only used the value after `.join` anyway and didn't care about threads killed by exceptions (single-thread run was mostly for debugging/local run).

That way, dictionaries (more than one in a single function) were used for appending new results in each run, without the need of collecting returned values manually and filtering them (the called function knew in which dict to put the result in, used lock to ensure thread safety).

---

Was it a "good" or "wrong" way of doing things?

In my opinion it was a *pythonic* way of doing things:

- easily readable in both forms - dealing with the result was the same in single- and multi-threaded
- data was "automatically" nicely formatted - as opposed to de-capsulating thread results, manual collecting and parsing them
- and fairly easy to understand - with first and last point in my list above ;)